RCA output from record player
I‘m an ECE student working on a personal project over winter break — I inherited a record player from my late grandfather (as well as a Carver receiver with pre-amp capabilities) and would like to build an ADC to convert the output to digital and cast to my Sonos speakers over Wi-Fi/Bluetooth. Currently prototyping on an Arduino MEGA board, and then planning to build out a PCB using ICs that have a higher sample rate/bit depth.
Right now, I’m trying to read the signals off the record player using my oscilloscope, and all I’m getting is a pretty smooth sine wave, albeit with some noise. Reading off the pre-amp’s output gives me a less noisy, amplified sine wave. Both outputs are a pair of RCA cables (I've since also tried the headphone output, which is phono-TRS, and it gives me something similar, a sine wave at about ~5V amplitude at ~1GHz frequency.)
Based on the little I know about audio signals, I would have expected a changing wave coming off the output, representing the needle’s position and therefore the audio signal. Could this be an issue with my oscilloscope settings (they’re just auto set currently), the way RCA cables work, or just a fundamental misunderstanding on my part about the way audio signals work?
Any input is much appreciated — I’ve tried Googling around but haven’t found anything too helpful yet. Thank you in advance!
EDIT:
Adding a photo here of the oscilloscope display and the record player/pre-amp:


For clarity, the signal I am reading on the oscilloscope is coming from the output of the headphone jack on the pre-amp/reciever. I have confirmed that plugging it directly into my guitar amp works as expected (I can hear the record playing), so everything is functional. Based on my knowledge, I had expected to see more of a "music" waveform, rather than a steady sinusoidal voltage. I also misstated the frequency -- it's nowhere near 1GHz, more like 1KHz if I'm not reading it wrong.
Thank you again, I'm very new to everything!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You should not get anything like 5 GHz from a record player, and you would need a very expensive oscilliscope to see it if you could.

Please show us some pictures of your setup, some scope pictures, and the model number of your scope.

@Mattman944 just edited with photos and some clarification! The scope is a Siglent SDS 1104 X-E.

That is 60 Hz from your line power. Possibly caused by a ground loop when you connected the scope. You should make a setup with Y cables so you can hear the music while you look at it with the scope. Then see if you can hear the 60 Hz when you connect the scope. 60 Hz is a nasty low buzzing sound.

Re, "...frequency -- it's nowhere near 1GHz, more like 1KHz..." Look closely at the extreme upper right corner of your oscilloscope screen shot.

Where did your get 1 GHz from?

@SolomonSlow I was doing my napkin math wrong -- it was picking up 60Hz AC. Now that I have a cleaner read on the audio signal by avoiding a ground loop, it's in the 100-200 KHz range.

Observing an AC power-induced 60 Hz sine wave on your scope suggests that the scope probes may be misconnected, looking like a floating ground. A proper connection should reveal audio waveforms, not a 60 Hz sine wave. Alternatively, the scope ground might not share the same potential as the record player, resulting in a ground loop. To avoid this, ensure the probe ground is attached to the chassis, and the probe tip is connected to the RCA connector's center conductor. See what that does for you, and get back to us.

This was the issue! I had the record player grounded to the chassis of the receiver, but the oscilloscope probe was grounded to the oscilloscope's own ground point (like I said, I'm a bit of a beginner despite four semesters of pre-requisite classes).
The oscope's FFT function also shows a much more reasonable output; I suspect that there might still be a little bit of 60 Hz AC in there, so I'll try putting a bandpass filter on it to get that out.

You are welcome.

Am I reading correctly that your Scope picture shows 60Hz measured frequency? I believe the the displayed 5ms/Div also suggests a rep frequency of ~66Hz (not the 1GHz you mentioned):
1/(3 divs * 5e-3sec) ≈ 66Hz
If so - you are likely only measuring the wall-plug / AC power frequency.  This is not the audio signal.  I would guess you're receiving that from radio waves/your audio cables acting as an antenna for the house' AC power.
Have you actually heard audio out of the record player yet?  That is, you know it is capable of producing audio thru the reciever and into speakers?  If not, first make sure it's capable of playing music - then you should indeed see a very complex waveform, definitely not a simple sine wave.
If you know it's producing audio output, then I think your scope settings need to be changed or your electrical connections aren't connecting between the inner/outer RCA plug contacts - but I suspect you're really not measuring the audio output at all, there is no signal at all so you see only the room's AC EM wave.

The solutions recommended here were correct -- I was creating a ground loop by grounding my record player and probe to different points.
Now that's fixed, I'm getting a much cleaner audio signal: 
And a more reasonable frequency domain:

I'm sure there are still some artifacts here, but I'm much closer. Thank you all for your help!

I am reading 6Vp 60 Hz which is rather excessive for a phono pickup but not for floating common mode pickup.  Your probe ground may be the cause.  Try using dual probe Ch A-B measurements and check the turntable chassis gnd. how is connected to RCA ground. This may need a separate ground cable to the Amp chassis. You may be measuring common mode hum.
Generally I expect SNR from the turntable to be around 80 dB SNR for old turntables due to motor magnetic crosstalk, and conductive ground loops.  I recall a faint hum from my old turntable with a Bogan tube amp back in the 60-70's. But I never succeeded in eliminating in Uni. then I was too busy at work and kids at home to bother later.
Moving coil needles are generally less prone to motor magnetic than moving magnet in coil pickup due to the smaller loop area.
The hum crosstalk is 60 Hz but is it magnetic or electrical crossstalk. Is it radiated or conducted?  Some tests can isolate which it is.

Use star chassis grounds where possible.

Isolate grounds to find current loops.

Physically isolate motor cables from coax.

Check shielding of magnetic pickup wire pairs is not connected to turntable.

Install or improve shielding around the motor using materials like Mu-metal or grounded copper tape to contain the motor’s electromagnetic field.

Ensure the neoprene shock mounts are well isolated as bass resonance can amplify hum by mechanical pickup.

Avoid running power and signal cables in parallel.

for Probe A-B measurements . You should expect a flat line when both probes are on the same point.  Twisting the identical 10:1 probe coaxes together is sometimes necessary to get down to uV levels. Without touching probe gnd or any other gnd. on a single probe, your body can pickup 60Vp e-field easily by squeezing the tip with your  1 nF finger tips across 10 Meg probe tip.


TL;DR There are some Youtube videos with good advice too. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYsihD8ptow
Move the turntable ! (?)
